# Can we write following if else statement with Ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

I want to find the easiest way to convert longer if else condition statement. Can we write following if else statement in more concise way?

```js
function pathology() {
  let pathologyValue = document.getElementById('pathologySuspecting').value;

  if (pathologyValue === 'Cushings') {
    document.getElementById('cushingsDetails').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('acromegalyDetails').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('otherPathologySuspectingDetails').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (pathologyValue === 'Acromegaly') {
    document.getElementById('cushingsDetails').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('acromegalyDetails').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('otherPathologySuspectingDetails').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (pathologyValue === 'Other') {
    document.getElementById('cushingsDetails').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('acromegalyDetails').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('otherPathologySuspectingDetails').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('cushingsDetails').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('acromegalyDetails').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('otherPathologySuspectingDetails').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
`
```

Comment: The ternary operator is not ES6

Comment: 1. How is ES6 relevant at all for this task? 2. How is a conditional operator going to be in any way better? 3. The usual pattern is to just set everything to `"none"` once and then use conditions to determine which one to set to `"block"`

Comment: Use classes. Hide all and show the relevant one

Comment: As already mentioned in the comments, there are much better ways to be concise (and even increase readability/understandability) than using the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ES6 to write it a lot more succinctly, but I would not use the ternary operator to do so:

```js
function pathology() {
  const target = document.querySelector("#pathologySuspecting").value;
  for (let [key, sel] of Object.keys({
    "Cushings": "#cushingsDetails",
    "Acromegaly": "#acromegalyDetails",
    "Other": "#otherPathologySuspectingDetails",
  })) {
    let e = document.querySelector(sel);
    e.style.display = (key === target) ? 'block' : 'none';  
  }
}
```

Note that there is no repetition in this code, compared to yours. Adding a new category would be 1 line.

Using classes, as in [mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70213687/15472) is even better - if all needed data is in the html, your JS becomes that much more maintainable, because you do not need to keep it in sync with the html.

Answer (score 0):

This is as concise  as it gets

```js
document.getElementById("pathologySuspecting").addEventListener("change", function() {
  let pathologyValue = this.value.toLowerCase();
  document.querySelectorAll(".details")
    .forEach(detail => detail.hidden = !detail.id.startsWith(pathologyValue))
});
```

```html
<select id="pathologySuspecting">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Cushings">Cushings</option>
  <option value="Acromegaly">Acromegaly</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>
<div id="cushingsDetails" class="details" hidden>Cushing</div>
<div id="acromegalyDetails" class="details" hidden>Acromegaly</div>
<div id="otherPathologySuspectingDetails" class="details" hidden>Other</div>
```

Shorter would be

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".details")
document.getElementById("pathologySuspecting").addEventListener("change", function() {
  divs.forEach((detail, i) => detail.hidden = i !== this.selectedIndex-1)
});
```

```html
<select id="pathologySuspecting">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Cushings">Cushings</option>
  <option value="Acromegaly">Acromegaly</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>

<div id="cushingsDetails" class="details" hidden>Cushing</div>
<div id="acromegalyDetails" class="details" hidden>Acromegaly</div>
<div id="otherPathologySuspectingDetails" class="details" hidden>Other</div>
```